# functions in OOP slider javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

Can someone tell me why my function doesn't work?

```
<body onload="changeImage();">
```

Javascript

```
var Slider = {
    monImage: document.getElementById('imgSlider1'),
    imageArray: ['img/slider/1.png', 'img/slider/2.png', 'img/slider/3.png'],
    imageIndex: 1,

    launch_functions_slider: function () {
        this.changeImage();
    },

    changeImage: function () {
        this.monImage.setAttribute('src', this.imageArray[this.imageIndex]);
        this.imageIndex++;
        if (this.imageIndex > 3) {
            this.imageIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

script.js

```
var mainSlider = {
    mainSlide: Object.create(Slider),
    Slider_run: function () {
        this.slide.launch_functions_slider();
    }
}
```

app.js

```
function appMap() {
    var slider_ = Object.create(mainSlider);
    slider_.Slider_run();
}
```

Comment: You can use : `Slider.changeImage();`

Comment: It change only one image, after my slider stay blocked

Comment: If you need to slideshow then you can setup using `setInterval(Slider.changeImage,1000);` or you can setup there `previous` and `next` link with event.
you can check here sample example: https://codepen.io/gabrieleromanato/pen/dImly

Comment: I'm gonna check this, thank you dude !

Comment: There is no iteration or timeout callbacks to continously iterate the images/slide. No wonder it changes only once.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an object method but you didn't use the object, try this,
`<body onload="Slider.changeImage()">`

Comment: What you expect from call this function?

Comment: Automatic slider (i very would like to use keyboard control on this, but i'm not good enough)

Comment: But your code example will not do what you said. Please use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to automaticaly call your function in time period. Or use a third party Slider plugin what you want to.